# Trouble importing array into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an `array` like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 123123123 [1] => Ognjen  [2] => Babic ) 
Array ( [0] => 23423423  [1] => Neven   [2] => Babic ) 
Array ( [0] => 235646345 [1] => Vanja   [2] => Babic ) 
Array ( [0] => 4853424   [1] => Nikola  [2] => Babic ) 
Array ( [0] => 34545747  [1] => Viktor  [2] => Sovilj )
```

And I really don't know how to import it into `mysql` database without using prepared statements, because I have a strict order not to use it. The main thing that confuses me is that I have never worked with this kinds of arrays before. Please help

Comment: Do one foreach loop then use implode function then save data as string in your DB

Comment: Why can't you use prepared statements?!

Comment: Is one of the requirements sanitizing the generated queries? If so you can just respond that it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to use prepared statements, try generating insert statements with the values in array and execute them one by one or in a batch

```
$upsert_query_str = "";
foreach($masterArray as $innerArray):
  //construct the update/insert query and append it to the string
  $upsert_query_str.="$$$$$$$$$$$$$";
endforeach;

//Execute the statements
```

OR

If you like to store all of the data against a specific row, use json_encode() and store it. when fetching it, use json_decode() and you'll have it in your grasp

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Considering **$DataArr** is your main array and you've done mysql Connection using mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword)

`$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) values ";`

```
$valuesArr = array();
foreach($DataArr as $row){

    $column1 = $row[0];    // values 123123123, 23423423, 235646345, etc
    $column2 = $row[1];    // values Ognjen, Neven, Vanja, etc
    $column3 = $row[2]     // values Babic, Sovilj, etc..

    $valuesArr[] = "('$column1', '$column2', '$column3')";
}

$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); `
```